# Pip installing tensorflow on Ubunutu EC2 instance - No space left on device, even though TMPDIR has plenty of space?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, pip

I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04. I had tensorflow 1.14 installed as I was trying to run a cloned repo but I needed to upgrade to tensorflow 2.2. I uninstalled tensorflow 1.14 and tried running `pip install tensorflow` but I get the following output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-2.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (516.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.8 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.3.3 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3" in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.34.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.29.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.3.0,>=2.2.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3" in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse==1.6.3 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.8.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (47.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.6.0.post3)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (4.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (2018.1.18)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

I have an EBS volume with 11 GiB of free space mounted as `/data/`. This is the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           376M  772K  375M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  5.6G  2.2G  73% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
/dev/xvdb        50G   40G   11G  79% /data
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
tmpfs           376M     0  376M   0% /run/user/1000
```

With pip, I tried specifying running with `--no-cache-dir` but it did not work. I set TMPDIR as my `data` partition; here is the output of `echo $TMPDIR`: `/home/ubuntu/../../data` (which is where my partition is)

I also tried `pip install --build=/ tensorflow` inside my data partition and got really odd behavior; it output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-2.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (516.2 MB)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tensorflow/tensorflow'
Check the permissions.
```

I ran the same command with `sudo` and got:

```
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: mock>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34>=1.1.6 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.14.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<1.15.0rc0,>=1.14.0rc0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.weakref>=1.0rc1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: futures>=2.2.0; python_version < "3.2" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from grpcio>=1.8.6->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow)
```

But this did not actually install tensorflow (as evidenced by `pip list`)

Answer (score 0):

> Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in **/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages**

vs

> Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages**

When you are using sudo. It seems to be switching to a different python.

> pip install --build=/ tensorflow

You used this with the absolute path pointing to root. Try with `.` relative to current directory or the absolute e.g. `/home/ubuntu/../../data` to your data partition. Making sure you have write permissions to that folder.

Comment: Everytime I need to write something in my data/ partition I have to use sudo - how can I give myself write permissions to that folder?

Comment: > how can I give myself write permissions to that folder?

Use `sudo chown <username>:<groupname> <data/ partition>`